# How do I validate a MYSQL Date field for NULL/ EMPTY?

Tags: mysql, validation, date, stored-procedures

I'm developing a MYSQL Stored Proc, and in that I need to validate a date field as follows,

```
IF (dt_wedding_date<>'') THEN
     IF (int_days_to_wedding>0) THEN
      SET vc_wedding ='F';
    ELSE
      SET vc_wedding ='P';
    END IF;
  ELSE
    SET vc_wedding = 'NA';
  END IF;
```

But when the **dt_wedding_date** is null it never goes to the ELSE part. I tried "is null", "is not null", ">", <>, trim functions, nothing worked.

Any idea how to evaluate this date field for nulls/empty?

Comment: All ordinary comparisons involving NULL return false. However, `IS NOT NULL` should have worked.

Answer (score 1):

try isnull function, I tried it on my local mysql

```
mysql> select * from data_test;
+----+------------+
| id | gmt_create |
+----+------------+
|  1 | NULL       |
+----+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, isnull(gmt_create) from data_test;
+----+--------------------+
| id | isnull(gmt_create) |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 |                  1 |
+----+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

from the [w3c reference](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

> MySQL does have an ISNULL() function. However, it works a little bit
>   different from Microsoft's ISNULL() function.